# Assignment by type in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to solve an assignment problem in excel but cannot achieve it yet. As you can see below I need to assign some jobs to some people. I have to do this by some rules;

1-Each assignment counts one and this adds on point cell. (aa has 2 points if I give it another job aa's new point became 3 points)

2-It is great if points are not bigger than 6.

3-If it is possible type 1 and type 2 must match. If it is not, any type2 can fit any type1.

I need to fill C and D (if job count is 2) with names column with considering type columns and point column. Can you please help me?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear, what's the relationship between 2 tables here

Comment: First table has works to do, each row at first table is one work. First column shows how many people need to do this work. Second column shows category of work. 
Second table has person names which these works needs to be assigned between. Points column shows works done by persons before. Type2 column shows these persons category priorities. I need to fill C and D column with these names based their priorities and points.